# How to use pkcss 11 usb token to digitally sign pdf from client side using php in server side and js

Tags: php, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have an office file management system built on php mysql . Now we have a requirement of digitally signing pdf which is dynamically generating from php and deliver it to the client.

Our scenario is ,the officer logins to the system from his browser and connecting his USB token and clicking some button in the webapp the document should be created in the server and the same should be digitally signed and stored in server as file .

1. In client side what program should be used. Can Java script do this ?
2. What will be the architecture for kind of application

Comment: That USB Key is a FIDO standard device key?

Comment: How to check that? I think it is FIPS

Comment: Ok Mate, try to find out what model and make is of this USB key, next maybe vendor provide any API (JS library) for this device.

Comment: Please check if this SO Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332133/9659885 can help... Working demo is available at http://web.signer.digital

Comment: You may give [this](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/fortify/#p-692) a try ([Fortify](https://fortifyapp.com/) = client side library to access local USB tokens or smart card + our commercial tool called [SetaPDF-Signer](https://www.setasign.com/signer) component = server side PDF signature solution written in PHP).